# Finding an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb Q[X]$ with real roots

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, totally-real-field

**Context.**

I was trying to prove that for a given $n$, there exist a totally real number field of degree $n$.

I understood that it was equivalent to find a polynomial $P$ such that

(i) $P\in\mathbb Q[X]$ ;

(ii) $P$ is irreducible ;

(iii) $P$ only has real roots in $\mathbb C$ ;

(iv) $P$ has degree $n$.

I succeeded in my initial problem thanks to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867852/totally-real-galois-extension-of-given-degree) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239316/mathbbqe2-pi-i-n-mathbbq-cos2-pi-n-1-text-or-2) two MSE questions.

But the construction is abstract, and I can not deduce from it an explicit polynomial satisfying the four conditions.

**The question.**

> For a given $n$, do you know how can I construct an explicit polynomial $P$ satisfying (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv)?

Comment: If by "Number field" you simply mean an algebraic extension of $\;\Bbb Q\;$ of finite degree then $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]2)\;$ is such an example for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ . But in this case condition (iii) isn't fulfilled...and I'm not sure whether this can be done.

Comment: @DonAntonio That's not totally real.

Comment: @Ravi What is "totally real" for you?

Comment: @DonAntonio Every embedding $\iota: K\hookrightarrow \mathbb C$ lands in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Totally real means that all the conjugates under the Galois group are subsets or $\mathbb R$. But this question is more about the polynomial.

Comment: @Ravi Ok, then it indeed is not...and of course your definition is equivalent to condition (iii) that I mentioned above. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that by "real roots in $\mathbb{C}$" you mean real roots (from $\mathbb{R}$). One possible family of polynomials that satisfy all these criteria (for $n\geq5$):

$$
f_n(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)+1.
$$

**Proof.**
Ad (i) and (iv) Trivial.

Ad (ii) This polynomial is well known to be irreducible, it follows nicely from irreducibility criterion of Pólya, see for example [Prove that the polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n) + 1$, $ n\ge1 $, $ n\ne4 $ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503765/prove-that-the-polynomial-x-1x-2-cdotsx-n-1-n-ne-4-is-irreducible/2792069#2792069) and/or linked questions.

Ad (iii) (sketch) This is a bit technical but can be done (holds for $n\geq 4$). Idea is that we have $f_n(i)=1$ for $i=1\dots n$. Now if we look at $f_n(k/2)$ for $k=1,3,\dots,2n-1$, we get another $n$ points, out of which $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ are negative. So by examining sign changes, we can reach the conclusion that $f(x)$ has exactly $n$ real roots.

**Remark:** The polynomial can be also slightly modified to avoid the limitation $n \geq 5$, for example $5\cdot (x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)+1$ can be shown to satisfy all the conditions for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Take an Eisenstein polynomial ( [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) ) $P(x)$ with integer coefficients for a prime $p$. Now consider $a$ integer such that $a+ Im(x_k)>0$ for all roots $x_k$ of $P(x)$ and moreover $a\equiv 0 \bmod{p^2}$. Then

1. $P(x- i a) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ has all the roots in the upper half plane.
2. $Re(P(x- i a))$ is  an Eisenstein polynomial for $p$.

Denote by $Q(x)=Re(P(x-ia))$.

From 1.  $Q(x)$ has all the roots real (and distinct) (see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791246/complex-polynomial-has-zeroes-only-in-the-upper-half-plane) )

From 2.  $Q(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Example: $P(x) = x^n+3$, $\ \ p=3$, $a=9$.
$$
Q(x)=1/2(\ (x+9i)^n+(x-9i)^n)+3 $$

Answer (score 3):

Take a polynomial with large integer coefficients with $n$ real roots.
Then perturb the coefficients slightly (add or subtract one from some
of them) to make the polynomial reduce modulo $2$ to an irreducible
polynomial modulo $2$. Your new polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$
and unless you have been unlucky or careless, will still have $n$ real
roots.

Comment: Thanks, it convinces me that it exists. But do you think we can deduce a more explicit polynomial from this construction?

Comment: For a more explicit example, take a prime $p\equiv1\pmod{2n}$. Take the Gaussian periods corresponding to the index $n$ subgroup of $\text{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)/\Bbb Q)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_period